# console application not displaying anything

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I've written a program in C using Visual Studio 2013 that calculates the average amount of time and paint dries based on three numerical values.

The program works fine without errors but when debugging, the console application displays nothing but the cursor blinking.
At first I thought it was just this program, but then I opened my past projects and the same thing happens when debugging.

When I debug on another machine the console application displays what's supposed to be printed by the program but my computer doesn't. Is it a problem with the compiler?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

/*This starting section of the code is where prompts are printed out to 
    make the user input the information required in order for the program to
    printout results based on the input.*/

```
int main(){
int numofpaints;
char paintname[30][10];
int time[3][10];
int meantime;
int var = 0;
int var2 = 0;
int hours;
int minutes;

printf("Input the number of paints you want:\n\n");
scanf("%d", &numofpaints);
```

/*This for loop is where the calculation for the average takes place as well as 
    the calculations to see if a paint qualifies to have quick drying status.*/

```
for (var = 0; var < numofpaints; var++)

{
    printf("please enter the name of the paint:\n\n");
    scanf("%s", paintname[var]);

    printf("How long did %s take to dry first the first time:\n\n", paintname[var]);
    scanf("%d", &time[0][var]);

printf("How long did %s take to dry for the second time:\n\n", paintname[var]);
    scanf("%d", &time[1][var]);

    printf("How did it take for %s to dry for the third time:\n\n", paintname[var]);
    scanf("%d", &time[2][var]);
}



for (var2 = 0; var2 < numofpaints; var2++)
{
    meantime = (time[0][var2] + time[1][var2] + time[2][var2]) / 3;
    hours = meantime / 60;
    minutes = meantime % 60;
```

/*These if statements are here to printout results based on the calculations made
    using the values the user's inputted through the keyboard. for example if the values
    a user inputted resulted in 5 then the appropriate statement would be used which would
    would be printing "5 hours" rather than "5 hours 0 minutes".*/

```
if (hours > 1 && minutes == 0)
    {
        printf("\n%s finished drying in %d hours. ", paintname[var2], hours);
    }
    else if (hours > 1 && minutes > 1)
    {
        printf("\n%s finished drying in %d hours and %d minutes. ", paintname[var2], hours, minutes);
    }
    else if (hours > 1 && minutes == 1)
    {
        printf("\n%s finished drying in %d hours and %d minute. ", paintname[var2], hours, minutes);
    }
    else if (hours == 0 && minutes != 1)
    {
        printf("\n%s finished drying in %d minutes. ", paintname[var2], minutes);
    }
    else if (hours == 1 && minutes == 1)
    {
        printf("\n%s finished drying in 1 hour and 1 minute. ", paintname[var2]);
    }
    else if (hours == 1 && minutes > 1)
    {
        printf("\n%s finished drying in 1 hour and %d minutes. ", paintname[var2], minutes);
    }
    else if (hours == 0 && minutes == 1)
    {
        printf("\n%s finished drying in %d minute. ", paintname[var2], minutes);
    }
    else if (hours == 1 && minutes == 0)
    {
        printf("\n%s finished drying in an hour. ", paintname[var2]);
    }
```

/*these if statements are determening if a paint qualifies as instant, quick or fast.
        the first if stament is stating if the average time calculated between the 3 inputted
        values is less than or equal to 1 hour/60 then it fits into the instant paint category. so each
        of the 3 statements will determine if a paint fits into eithier instant, quick or fast.*/
        if (meantime < 360)
            printf("This means %s qualifies ", paintname[var2]);
        else

```
        printf("This means %s did not qualify.\n\n\n", paintname[var2]);

if (meantime <= 60)
    {
        printf("and\nit'll fit into the category of instant paint.\n\n\n", paintname[var2]);
    }
    else if (meantime <= 119){
        printf("and\nit'll fit into the category of fast paint.\n\n\n", paintname[var2]);
    }
    else if (meantime <= 359){
        printf("and\nit'll fit into the category of quick paint.\n\n\n", paintname[var2]);
    }
        else{

        }


}
```

}

Comment: please, post some code

Comment: Your program is not the problem, it works fine. You have some configuration problem with Visual Studio. Try to reinstall it.

Comment: re-installing worked took some since i had remove all the previous files that came with VS but thanks